# Como formatar valor em php?

Tags: php

tenho o seguinte código

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$id_empresa = $_GET['id_empresa'];
$data = $_GET['data'];

$tipo = "ENT";
$valorTotalE = 0;

$valorTotalEntradas=$pdo->prepare('SELECT valor FROM importa
                                                        WHERE data=:data
                                                        AND id_empresa=:id_empresa
                                                        AND tipo=:tipo');

$valorTotalEntradas->bindValue('id_empresa', $id_empresa);
$valorTotalEntradas->bindValue('data', $data);
$valorTotalEntradas->bindValue('tipo', $tipo);
$valorTotalEntradas->execute();

while ($linha=$valorTotalEntradas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $valor = $linha['valor'];
    $valorTotalE = $valorTotalE + $valor;

    $valorTotalE = number_format($valorTotalE,2,',','.');

    $return = array(
        'valorTotalE' => $valorTotalE
    );

}

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

Essa linha de comando "$valorTotalE = number_format($valorTotalE,2,',','.');" formata o valor em 9.999,99, porém, ele faz isso que aparece na imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pra mim a imagem parece correta com o exemplo `9.999,99`, o ponto separa milhar e a virgula separa os centavos. O que exatamente você esperava que ocorresse?

Comment: Aonde faz sua pergunta? O que há de errado ? =(

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. note que o valor de 16.269,70 é para ser a soma dos 4 valores acima.

Comment: @RafaelSalomão, mesma resposta que dei ao Guilherme.

Comment: Você esta tentando somar strings com formato não numerico, formato de dinheiro/moeada não é numero.

Comment: Faço minhas as palavras do @GuilhermeNascimentoP., você precisa converter o valor em float

Comment: Se eu não coloco a linha $valorTotalE = number_format($valorTotalE,2,',','.'); o valor aparece somado, mas sem essa formatação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você esta tentando somar depois de usar o `number_format`, isso não tem sentido, só pode se somar o que for numero como strings que podem fazer o cast ou tipos `int`, `float` e `bool`

Veja se fizer isto irá obter o erro:

```
<?php

$valor1 = 'foo';
$valor2 = '2';
$valor3 = '3';

$total = $valor1 * $valor2 * $valor3;
```

Ou seja a mensagem indica que você esta tentando fazer uma operação matemática sem ter um numero valido:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

Basta usar o `number_format` depois:

```
while ($linha=$valorTotalEntradas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $valor = $linha['valor'];
    $valorTotalE = $valorTotalE + $valor;

}

//Aqui você usa o number_format
$valorTotalE = number_format($valorTotalE, 2, ',', '.');

echo json_encode(array(
    'valorTotalE' => $valorTotalE
));
```

Note que para isto funcionar no banco de dados você deve usar `DECIMAL` na coluna 
`valor`, se usar `varchar` e o formato não for numérico é capaz de falhar também.

Comment: Desculpe Guilherme, mas veja, novamente, o meu código, isso que você disse é que não faz sentido "O problema é que vc esta tentando somar depois de usar o number_format, isso não tem sentido".

Comment: @GustavoSevero só tem um return, a resposta explica aonde esta a sua falha, number_format é só necessário depois da soma toda, e vc esta tentando fazer antes, teste o exemplo. Editei o código, tinha um `;` errado, leia aonde comentei `"//Aqui você usa o number_format"`

Comment: Certo, coloquei o number_format dentro do $return e consegui:

$return = array(
  'valorTotalE' => number_format($valorTotalE,2,',','.')
 );

Agora sim funcionou.
Eu não estava entendo você dizendo que eu estava colocando o number_format antes da soma kkkk

Comment: Da forma como vc deixou na solução, não funciona, pois eu fazia isso dava errado.

Comment: @GustavoSevero "não funciona" é extremamente vago, não funciona o que? O que acontece? Dá pra explicar?

Comment: Não aparecem os valores somados.

Comment: @GustavoSevero continuo não entendendo, não aparece ou aparece errado. Explica melhor por favor.

Comment: Esquece, refiz como vc colocou e deu certo. Desculpe.